# How to connect 2 + 2 monitors to a Radeon RX 460

Tags: hdmi, displayport, splitter, extended-desktop

Starting Position:

- 1 Dell Workstation running Ubuntu 18.04
- 1 Sapphire Radeon RX 460
- 4 LG 24" 24MB65PY-B WUXGA monitors (that is my limit, no need for higher res)

The RX 460 has three outputs:

- DVI
- HDMI
- Display Port

The 4 LG monitors have three inputs:

- D-SUB
- DVI-D
- Display Port

What I'd like to do:

I'd like to have two monitors in room A and two in room B (there's a hole in the wall for the cables). So in room A one will see the same extended screen on two displays as in room B (i.e. clone).

The distance from the PC and the monitors in room A is rather short, like 1.2 m.
But the distance to the second couple of monitors (in room B) is for sure more than 5 m but less than 10 m.

As the Radeon is capable of running an extended view setup, I was thinking of using two of its outputs with a splitter in each line to distribute the signal. So at that point I hope for your kind advice/hints/experiences.

Considering that HDMI splitters seem to be much cheaper than DP splitters, I am thinking to use HDMI splitters
So from the first output (HDMI) I'd go directly into the splitter and then with HDMI/DP cables to the displays.
The second output (DP) would need an adapter to the HDMI-splitter and then again the HDMI/DP cables to the monitors.

Will this work? Or do I overlook something crucial? Are there better ways to achieve what I have in mind? Any thoughts are highly appreciated.

Comment: Cloning is what I meant by "one will see the same extended screen" but I just edited the post to make this clear.

Comment: Dasiy Chain is probably not an option as the monitors do not have a DP output, and by what I read this is a requirement for daisy chaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made it work. So this is merely to close the question and to share my experience.
The basic setup is still as described in my original post, but with some changes:

- Instead of using the DP cables I used HDMI, as DP cables are more expensive and currently a little hard to get. I use 2 x 10 metres for room B and have not encountered any problems yet.
- I used adapters from HDMI to DVI wherever required, i.e. at all four monitors and at the output of the Radeon card.
- I used two active HDMI splitters.

The commissioning went not without problems, as the OS had problems to identify the monitor correctly, hence the native resolution was not available. The solution was some unplugging and re-plugging in different combinations and of course restarting, and eventually things run as expected.